# Is there a safe way to access this site

Tags: security, help, connection, troubleshooting, url

" https://thewest.com.au/digital-edition?utm_source=SSW&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=digital-edition&utm_term=read-the-digital-edition&utm_content=top-nav "
I am a paid subscriber to this digital newspaper. I understand the reason why the website would not allow me access if they suspect anything but normal when I try to access the site and I also understand if TOR will see this attempted access as a security risk but can someone say if there is a safe way to gain access. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think I have found a possible solution. Try using: https://hidester.com/proxy/ as a proxy. It might let you access https://thewest.com.au. Or you can try using another website as a proxy since  there are many free proxy servers available (https://www.fossmint.com/free-proxy-for-anonymous-web-browsing/). However, I strongly discourage logging in if it is even possible. After all, the third-party proxy server would be handling your data.

[image]

---

From what I've checked, the entire website (not just the link you gave) doesn't work with the Tor network. It is most likely due to the one of these two reasons:

1. The website is blocking Tor. Some sites may simply refuse to allow Tor users or may give them Captchas. Many websites block Tor exit nodes since some (not all) individuals use it for spamming, distributing malware, cyber attacking, etc. Of course, the majority of Tor users don't intend to do this, but for security purposes, the website might block Tor users.
2. The Tor network breaks the website. Some sites cannot handle traffic coming from the Tor network and may not work. For example, https://reddit.com doesn't work with the Tor network and gives a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error so you would have to use https://old.reddit.com with Tor as a fix.

If this website falls into category 2, then it depends on the website owner to fix the issue and you would have to contact and request them to do so.

If this website falls into category 1, there wouldn't be much you can do other than contacting the site to talk about the issue.

As a sidenote, I noticed that the website **might** allow **some** proxies as seen below. Maybe you could try using a proxy with the Tor network though I wouldn't guarantee success. It probably won't work.

[image]

Ultimately, contacting the website owners themselves is the best option since they own the site. They probably can give you information on how to solve the issue or will explain why if you can't solve the issue. I hope this helps!

Contact website: https://thewest.com.au/contact